# Place UIImageViews in row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am looping through a array and adding UIImageViews, the array has a have different count depending on somethings. So the amount of UIImageViews varies. What I need to do is line them up in a row in the center of the view. I know the code that I need to use its the calculations that I am having an issue with.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [_lettersArray count]; i++){

    UIImage* imageContainer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"container.png"];
            UIImageView *containerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageContainer];
            containerView.frame = CGRectMake(???,120,imageContainer.size.width,imageContainer.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
}
```

Comment: Since no one has a clue what you are doing, it is impossible to help. Post the related code you are trying and explain what it is doing and what you want it to do.

Comment: i had updated example for your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self _layoutViews:self.imageViews inView:self.view];

- (void) _layoutViews:(NSArray *)views inView:(UIView *)contentView
{
    NSInteger overallWidth = 0;
    for ( UIView *view in views ) {
        overallWidth += view.frame.size.width;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
    CGFloat startOffset = (contentSize.width - overallWidth)/2.0;
    CGFloat offset = startOffset;
    for ( UIView *view in views ) {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = offset;
        frame.origin.y = (contentSize.height/2.0) - (frame.size.height/2.0);
        view.frame = frame;
        offset += view.frame.size.width;
    }
}
```

For your example code it would be something like this:

```
    CGFloat count = [_lettersArray count];
    NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < [_lettersArray count]; i++) {
        UIImage *imageContainer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"container.png"];
        UIImageView *containerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageContainer];
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,120,imageContainer.size.width,imageContainer.size.height);
        [imageViews addObject:containerView];
        [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    }

    [self _horizontalCenterViews:imageViews inView:self.view];

    return YES;
}

- (void) _horizontalCenterViews:(NSArray *)views inView:(UIView *)contentView
{
    NSInteger overallWidth = 0;
    for ( UIView *view in views ) {
        overallWidth += view.frame.size.width;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
    CGFloat startOffset = (contentSize.width - overallWidth)/2.0;
    CGFloat offset = startOffset;
    for ( UIView *view in views ) {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = offset;
        view.frame = frame;
        offset += view.frame.size.width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works really good, the only thing I noticed is that the UIImageViews are not really in the center they are more to the left. Thanks again.

Comment: In my example i used self.window instead of self.view, but if you really use self.view and this not works correct, check your view.autoresizingMask, may be your view have not correct size. And if your view's size changing, you should recalculate frame for imageViews